# Computer does a boot loop

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, power-supply

My computer is -or looks like so- stuck in a "boot loop". When I power it on it'll start normally (LEDs, fans etc) but will stop after ~ 1 seconds. Then will wait about 2-4 seconds and try again and again and again...

The last time I used it, I played CS:GO while chatting with friends on Discord, and shut it down normally.

I already changed the cable, and I changed of electrical outlet, that did nothing. The cable is not plugged to a power bar.

I searched the Internet and found it might comes from the RAM, MB or PSU but how do I know? What can I do to diagnose the problem?

**EDIT**: It is a desktop computer.

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a laptop or a desktop computer?

You should try unplugging it and remove the battery (if any). Wait for a few minutes then try again.

There could be a lot of problems, but the easiest to start with is the RAM. Remove all but one stick and try again.

If it's a desktop computer, start removing components one by one, except for the CPU of course and one stick of RAM.

Comment: Oh sorry I should've said it was a desktop computer. Editing the OP now, and trying what you said. Will come back with (hopefully) good results!

Comment: No worries. Also, with only one stick of RAM, if you still don't have POST, try installing it in another slot. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure why, but I removed one stick of RAM, powered on fine. Removed the other and plugged back the first, powered on fine, plugged back the second, powered on fine. Thanks man, and if you have an explanation of why I'll take it!

Comment: Ha ha! Great. Prolly one of the RAM sticks was a bit loose, or the connectors had some oxidizing or even dust and not properly connected...

Comment: Well, thanks again, you prolly saved me either hours of researchs or a good $50 to go to the repair guy. Btw posting that comment from my desktop ;)

Comment: Glad to be of help. 

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that a PRO and it may not be the right answer but I hope it helps...

I think that 1 second is too fast so maybe it's not starting to boot yet. .

I just have a few questions:

- Is the boot screen showing when you start your PC?
- What does the monitor show?
- What is your Operating System?
- Can you access your BIOS?

It may be a hardware-related problem. Try to clean your CPU and re-assemble it. And if you have multiple PCs, try to test every parts of your computer to another PC.

Comment: Sorry to made you type all that for nothing, the problem was fixed by removing the RAM and plugged it in again. Thanks anyway man!

Comment: Not a problem. I joined this community to learn more about Hardware and just now I already learned something. Thanks for the info !!

Answer (score -1):

One thing to try that i usually dont see mentioned is to look at the psu connections to the power and reset buttons.
I had a similar issue that started with random shutdowns but turned into a boop loop and the power button not always working and only by moving and reseating the wires did it stop happening. Turned out either the reset or power button was somehow being pressed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1157483)